# How to add XSL line in XML created by PHP DOMDocument()?

Tags: php, html, xml

In a nutshell: creating a xml document with PHP DOMDocument(). Need to add a line to the document.

Successfully creating an XML document with:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->formatOutput = true;


  $r = $doc->createElement( "products" );
  $doc->appendChild( $r );

  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
  {
      $b = $doc->createElement( "product" );


      //adding child elements.....
  }

  echo $doc->saveXML();
  $doc->save("write.xml")
```

However, at the top of the xml document I need to link to an xls.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my.xsl"?>
```

How do I add that line in the PHP, to the dynamically generated xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the manual for DOMDocument, there is actually an example to do exactly what you need in the `createProcessingInstruction` method, @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php